# Blazor Wasm Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'blazorCulture.get'

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly) and implemented the localization for my Blazor Wasm as 100% as in the article. Microsoft suggests to invoke js at the application start as below.

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization();

var host = builder.Build();

CultureInfo culture;
var js = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
var result = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");

if (result != null)
{
    culture = new CultureInfo(result);
}
else
{
    culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("blazorCulture.set", "en-US");
}

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

await host.RunAsync();
```

This works fine but sometimes when I open the start page, it returns a Js error telling me that

> ```
> blazor.webassembly.js:1 Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'blazorCulture.get' ('getBlazorCulture' was undefined).
> blazor.webassembly.js:1 Error: Could not find 'blazorCulture.get' ('blazorCulture.get' was undefined).
> ```

When I press contol+f5 to force reload cached data, error goes away. What could cause this problem and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**  Below how my Index.html Body looks like, here I suspect that since cultureget.js cultureset.js are the last, other js files loading takes longer than Blazor start although it doesnt happen always. So since blazor already started and last js files are loaded after blazor start, this error occurs. Question is is there way to ensure all js files are loaded before Blazor started? Of course quicker fix could be here to move those js right after blazor.webassembly.js.

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- third party -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-logger/src/logger.min.js"></script>

<!-- custom code -->
<script type="module" src="_content/logger.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="_content/eventHandlerUtils.js"></script> 
<script src="_content/cultureget.js"></script>
<script src="_content/cultureset.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you put the relevant JS implementation in the index.html or in another file? When does that message tends to happen? I have use that exact code in my app, I do not have that issue.

Comment: @Shuryno yes in the index.html right after blazor.webassembly.js. It happens randomly after changing language dynamically.

Comment: It occurs even on Start page reload as Program.cs is called again. It looks like that Js invoke is faster somehow.

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce with no success. Did you use the PWA install feature on your local debug by any chance? Also, did you put this flag BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData  to true?

Comment: @Shuryno see my Edit above please

Comment: @BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData true is set in the csproj file. I am not using PWA

Comment: I guess you should try to put those file higher up. Also, do you use a splash screen while waiting for the app to be downloaded and loaded? The default Blazor projects uses  <div id="app">Loading...</div> but I use something more custom made. If you took it out, it might explain why I do not experience this issue? /shrug I am trying to think outside the box

Comment: @Shuryno I am using the default Loading.. I am thinking as another option to start blazor manually with  <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        Blazor.start();
      });
    </script>

this can ensure that scripts are loaded first than Blazor starts. however I am not sure if it can cause other sideeffect, not used before

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you more, I do not load as mush 3rd party content(I have only Blazored.modal), maybe it makes a difference?

Comment: "Of course quicker fix could be here to move those js right after blazor.webassembly.js" Why not before? I guess you should put the js file starting Blazor last since Blazor might use some of the other js files and not the other way around.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine thats a good point. I have also thought like that first but in all MS official examples, they always have blazor.webassembly.js as first in the row. Could this eventually cause another exception if putting other js before that?

Comment: @Emil I don't see why it would, however you should avoid including JS files that executes some initialization code on DOM because it might not be fully loaded yet or it might be canceled with the next render.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine what is your suggestion instead? MS doesnt mention anywhere in their documentation regarding this issue.

Comment: If you want to execute some code regarding DOM with Javascript, you could probably call the JS functions in OnInitializedAsync or in OnAfterRenderAsync with IJSRuntime. However, I just meant be careful with JS files that execute directly some code over some HTML elements when included, it all depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following code patch because I was having the same problems. However, a better solution should be found. However, if we provide an error message to the user, they will be able to comprehend what went wrong.

Add the try-catch for getting culture into the **program.cs**. Update your **MainLayout.razor** with the following code:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
         var getCulture = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(getCulture) && !CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture!.Name.Equals(getCulture))
         {
              // Show error popup or toastr
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you show this to the user? it is not a visible error for the user. Correct culture will be still taken. it just in the console shows an error but user doesnt see any UI error.

Comment: I'm sharing this since the user is stuck on this culture error because they can't notice any UI changes. (According to the user, 'When I press control+f5 to force reload cached data, the error goes away.')

Comment: ok your problem seems to be different. in my case, i didnt have issue to get the new culture, only i was seeing error in console.